# Homeomorphism and partitions

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, recreational-mathematics

This was proposed by my lecturer as an excercise with no grade at all. However, I found it tricky to understand and solve.

Given the partition $\mathcal{D}=\{c_r|r\in[0,\infty)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $c_r$ is the circumference with radius $r$ and center at the origin, prove $(\mathcal{D},\tau_\mathcal{D})$ is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$ as a subspace of $(\mathbb{R},\tau_\mathbb{R})$ ($\tau_\mathbb{R}$ the usual topology).

I have made my research, and found that a circumference cannot be homeomorphic to any open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ so, I do not know how to start from here and find a function $f$ to give the homeomorphism.

Comment: It doesn't matter what $c_r$ is homeomorphic to. The structure of $c_r$ is irrelevant. You just treat $c_r$ as an element of $D$, and map it to $r$ in ${\bf R}$.

Comment: What you do need to worry about is the topology on $\cal{D}$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani So, the topology on $\mathcal{D}$ is the set of all open sets where the circles have no circumference? And the function $f$ would be the one that goes from $[0,r)$ to $[0,\infty)$? Meaning a function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You probably are supposed to consider the [quotient topology](https://stevenclontz.github.io/intro-to-topology/section-quotient.html) induced by the partition.

Comment: @StevenClontz I got that from the $[0,1]\rightarrow S^1$ we get $f(x)=(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x))$. However, how do I get $f$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Let $p \colon \Bbb R^2 \to [0,\infty)$ be the map $(x,y) \mapsto \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. If $\sim$ is the relation on $\Bbb R^2$ given by $$(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2) \iff p(x_1,y_1) = p(x_2,y_2),$$ then $\mathcal D = \Bbb R^2/{\sim}$ and $\tau_\mathcal{D}$ is the usual quotient topology.

Comment: You need a map $f$ from $D$ to the reals, and that map is given by $f(c_r)=r$.